# Magento 2: Get disabled products for a category in a collection programatically

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I want to get disabled products for a category in product collection programatically in Magento 2.2.5. I am using following code:

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}
public function deleteProductsByCategoryId($id)
{



    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($id);
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        // no disabled products are gotten
    }


}
```

But above code does not get disabled products.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Inject **Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory** in your construct and try to use this code :

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
) {
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function getProductCollection($category_id_array)
{
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $category_id_array]);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    return $collection;
}
```

Remove var and generated folder and check it.

Comment: Hi @Rohan Hapani, I need to get all enabled and disabled products from a particular category. Is this any possible way?

Answer (score -1):

The following function is doing what you need:

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->productCollection = $productCollectionFactory;
    }

public function deleteProductsByCategoryId($id)
        $productCollection = $this->productCollection->create();
        $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $productCollection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => array($id)));
        $productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('status', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);

        foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
        }
    }
```